# Sporadic JQuery error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, frontend, jquery-chosen

I'm getting sporadic JQuery/Javascript error:
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

This happens when I clicks on next, next in a series of search result pages.

The error does not always happen, for every 9-10 clicks on "next", I get it.
See screenshot here: [image]

I recently started using the chosen.js JQuery plugin.  Not sure if this has something to do
with this error.

The error doesn't mention specific lines of application javascript code.

It seems this error happens quite alot based on a google search.

What does the error mean?  Why does it only happen sporadically?
What types of things I can try to eliminate it?

Thank you

Comment: The error means that you're ending up with `undefined` before a function invocation operator ( `()` or `(x, y, z)` etc). Usually means that there's something like `foo.bar()` where "foo" is supposed to be an object that has a property called "bar", but in some cases it's not really an object or else it has no property called "bar".

Comment: You need to go up the stack until you get to code in your application. Post the code around that.